# How to pass current_user in every record on user_id veritable? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, associations, nested-forms

I want to pass `user_id` from current_user to every association in my nested form.

```
def create
    @entity = Entity.new(entity_params.merge(user: current_user)) 

    # entity has_many :boxes and in form i'm making them more than one
    @entity.boxes.user_id = current_user.id if current_user 

    # entity has_many :orders and in form i'm making them more than one
    @entity.orders.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
end
```

I'm getting this error

> undefined method `user_id='

I need a way how can I give every `box` and `order` user_id = current_user. All tables in database has user_id column and every model has `belongs_to :user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@entity.boxes` and `@entity.orders` are of type `<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`, i.e. you have to iterate on them in order to obtain the individual items `box` and `order` which have the associated `user`:

```
@entity.boxes.each do |box|
  box.user_id = current_user.id if current_user.present?
end
```

If you want to save the changes to the database you can also use:

```
box.update!(user: current_user) if current_user.present?
```

P.S. I suppose that `User` `has_many` `:boxes` and `:orders`

Comment: i added extra line `box.paper.each do ...` and it worked also for has many through association! Thanks